# Why aren't my Git updates via terminal working?

Tags: git, github, terminal, command-line-interface

So I'm working through The Odin Project and I'd like to add my solution here:
https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/javascript/lessons/library

TOP directions say to fork the original repository: `git clone git@github.com:your_user_name_here/theodinproject.git` as origin and `remote add upstream git@github.com:TheOdinProject/theodinproject.git`

But neither of those have the student solution file I want to change, so I set it as origin `https://github.com/acchang/curriculum.git` and upstream `https://github.com/TheOdinProject/curriculum.git`

I went to `curriculum/javascript/organizing-js` where I found the file I wanted to change, added and committed.

When I performed the next step `git fetch upstream`, I got:

```
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So then I up a few levels and did this and it updated:
My-MacBook-Air:the_odin_project acchang$ git fetch upstream

And then at that level, I wen to `git checkout master` and executed `git merge upstream/master` and got a message `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.` and `Already up to date.`

Next I did `git checkout your_feature_name` and `git merge master` and got similar messages, `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.` and `Already up to date.`

So then I do `git push origin master` and some code runs:

```
Enumerating objects: 14, done.
Counting objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 3.99 KiB | 2.00 MiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/acchang/curriculum.git
   5601f3a3a..9a4939b1e  master -> master
```

So there were changes. But the changes were not in the student solutions file I updated. If I got https://github.com/acchang/curriculum, it says `This branch is 3 commits ahead of TheOdinProject:master.`

And if I press "Compare," the differences are that there are a new "Calculator" folder with three files in it. I built a calculator weeks ago as part of the TOP work, and somehow it must have gotten mixed in.

Can you advise on how to solve this? I tried deleting the curriculum repository and starting anew but it didn’t work. I don’t know why the calculator folder and files are showing, and why my change to student solutions isn’t registering.

Is there a way to erase everything and start over again? Would that be the best strategy?

I've been using the instructions here, and I managed to upload them for a previous project.  https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-programming/lessons/using-git-in-the-real-world#a-git-workflow-for-open-source-contribution

I'll admit I only have the faintest idea of what I'm doing.

I went so far as the erase my original clone of https://github.com/TheOdinProject/curriculum, where the student solution would go, but I keep running into the same issue. And shouldn't erasing the repo have eliminated the calculator files?

Comment: How did you set `upstream`? What does `git remote -v` print?

Comment: Thanks for looking! I think I figured it out -- I just redid everything, using `git remote -v` to see where my origin and remote were pointing, and actually edited those repositories with `git remote add upstream` and `git remote add origin`. I think one of them may have not changed when I was trying to update that document. Plus, whenever I was branching, I was doing it from probably too high up in the file tree, I needed to zoom in more.